# Sitefinity 5.3 displaying Culture info at the end of URL

Tags: cultureinfo, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

I recently upgraded a website to Sitefinity 5.3. For some reason, when I try to edit a page  in the backend, it throws a '**500 - Internal server error**' . On close inspection, I see that the culture appears at the end of the URL instead of the usual position after the base URL. E.g.  The URL shows as

http://www.mywebsite.com/my-page/Action/Edit/en

instead of the usual

http://www.mywebsite.com/en/my-page/Action/Edit

Any  idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yosief,

That only occurs in the backend. If you load up the translated front-end page, you will notice that the translation appears before the page alias.

Thanks - Chris

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it always has been on the end of the url.
Is it working when you put the culture at the other position?

Regards,
Daniel